# Cannot get the label's property value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have a small `JavaScript` code which is called on a button click event.

What I want is just to access an html label property when some validation fails.

I have the following code:

```
if (datePicker1.get_selectedDate() == null && datePicker2.get_selectedDate() == null) {
      //alert("At least one date should be selected");
        alert($('#lblValidate').attr('id'));
      //$('#lblValidate').css("visibility","visible");                
        eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
       }
```

I commented out some code for a moment.
The first alert works, however when trying to display an alert to show a label's `id` property, alert is not shown.

This is the label:

```
<label id="lblValidate" style="visibility:visible; color:red;">Enter a valid date</label>
```

What I eventually want to accomplish is have a label hidden and then when the validation fails, to  set the label's `css` to `visible`, instead of showing an alert.

But, somehow, I cannot display a label attribute in the alert at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are selecting label with id attribute and trying to get id attribute it self!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: `.text()`, not `.attr("id")`; [details](https://api.jquery.com). Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others.

Comment: No matter if I change it to `.text()`. The point is, the code doesn't execute at all when trying to get the value from a label.

Comment: is $('#lblValidate') actually finding the label element when you debug it ?  maybe check out http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html